# How to scale layout in mobile device for height

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport, adaptive-layout

I'm building a mobile site that needs to be used equally on all mobile screens.

All dimensions in the layout are obtained for a screen of 1080 for 1920, while only the width is scaled normally on a mobile device, scrolling appears in height. How can I scale the site in height as well, avoiding using % everywhere in css?

**Example:** [image]

For width, viewport `width=device-width` is used, but for height, property `height=device-height` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can try experimenting with `vh` css unit.

Also see: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If I set the height to 100vh there is not enough space in my layout for components and I need to set all sizes in css to vh